# Differences in require vs require.ensure for code-splitting in webpack 2

Tags: webpack, requirejs, code-splitting

For **Webpack 2**, does `require()` do anything different than `require.ensure()` for code spitting?

I have a project that was converted from a `requirejs` base and `require()` still works and appears to be splitting my app appropriately. Is there any reason I should change to `require.ensure()` instead?